# using functions instead of methods in SomethingRequest for validation

Tags: function, validation, laravel-5, methods, request

I would like to validate different variables by calling a special function in request in Laravel. How could I do it?

```
if ($this->function() == 'function1') {
     return [
                'firstName' => 'required|unique:networks,name|min:2',
            ];
} elseif ($this->function() == 'function2') {
     return [
                'lastName' => 'required|unique:networks,name|min:5'
            ];
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::post('increase-credit/{value?}', 'testController@function1');
Route::post('increase-credit-by-admin/{value?}', 'testController@function2');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can name your routes and then in the FormRequest return different rules depend on the route name:

```
Route::post('increase-credit/{value?}', 'testController@function1')->name('route1');
Route::post('increase-credit-by-admin/{value?}', 'testController@function2')->name('route2');
```

In the FormRequest:

```
if ($this->route()->getName() == 'route1') {
    return [
        rule1
    ];
if ($this->route()->getName() == 'route2') {
    return [
        rule2
    ];
}
```